# Sentry android ANR, could there be a false alarm?

Tags: java, android, sentry

I'm using Sentry-Android 2.3.0 SDK to collect android crashes and ANR, for the past few months, there were a couple of weird ANRs showing up. All of them happened when the user turned on the device after some time, all of them happened in the `MessageQueue.next` method. After digging in the Sentry SDK source code a bit, I found the core logic for dealing with ANR in Android lies in class [ANRWatchDog.java](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/blob/main/sentry-android-core/src/main/java/io/sentry/android/core/ANRWatchDog.java), which IMHO can be simplified as follows:

```
public class Test {
  BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

  class MainThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
      while (!isInterrupted()) {
        Runnable r;
        try {
          r = queue.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { return; }
        r.run();
      }
    }
  }

  class WorkerThread extends Thread {
    private AtomicLong tick = new AtomicLong(0);
    private AtomicBoolean reported = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private final Runnable ticker = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        tick = new AtomicLong(0);
        reported.set(false);
      }
    };

    public void run() {
      while (!isInterrupted()) {
        boolean needPost = tick.get() == 0;
        tick.addAndGet(100L);
        if (needPost) {
          queue.add(ticker);
        }
        try {
          Thread.sleep(100L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          return;
        }

        if (tick.get() != 0 && !reported.get()) {
          // TODO: if ActivityManager available, further check
          reported.set(true);
          throw new RuntimeException("Bang!");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, shouldn't the tick variable be `volatile`? Can this code cause visibility issues? If so, will this code result in false alarm in production code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik `AtomicLong` getter and setter read/write from volatile fields so not necessary, we've made improvements to this algo to avoid false/positives, please upgrade the SDK to the latest version.

One of the main changes is: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/blob/main/sentry-android-core/src/main/java/io/sentry/android/core/ANRWatchDog.java#L95-L117

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my concern is if there is a scenario when ActivityManager is not available like when user return to the app after a long time, and [this reassign to a non-final non-volatile reference](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/blob/main/sentry-android-core/src/main/java/io/sentry/android/core/ANRWatchDog.java#L35) (although it's a reference to an AtomicLong, we didn't use its getter/setter in main thread) triggered an visibility issue, we could miss the `needPost` condition in WatchDog thread, thus trigger a timeout

Comment: that's true, `tick` could be `final` and do `tick.set(0);` instead of `tick = new AtomicLong(0);`
Would you like to submit a PR?